# webkitRelativePath not available in expressjs fileupload

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I'm trying to get 'webkitRelativePath' with Expressjs file-upload module but isn't available. Any solution in fixing this issue ?

The file object looks like:
[image]

HTTP request:
[image]

Express (req.files)
[image]

How you can see, the ExpressJS log contain only filename without absolute path of file and I need to know where is the file located to create the required folders with Node file-system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figgured out how to fix it. ExpressJS Fileupload middleware uses `path.basename` to extract the filename from path to be returned as 'name'.

The solution that works here is to send the file name encrypted (I have used window.btoa) to encrypt the file name so that the Fileupload middleware doesn't know where to cut the path to extract the name and it leaves it like it is.

Then I have simply used `atob()` to decrypt the file name that is actually a path.

**Front-end:**

```
function handleFolderSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;

    var fd = new FormData();
    _.each(files,(v,k)=>{
        fd.append('files', files[k], window.btoa(files[k].webkitRelativePath)); // Encrypt path
    });

    $http.post('/upload/directory', fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    }).then(function(resp){
        // Do something
    });
}

document.getElementById('browse-directory').addEventListener('change', handleFolderSelect, false);
```

**Back-end**

```
app.post('/upload/directory', cors(corsOptions), (req,res)=>{

    _.each(req.files.files,(file,key)=>{
        file.name = atob(file.name); // Decrypt path
    });

    // Process data

});
```

FormData: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

atob / btoa: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined"  in the client side